# error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG error while pushing app to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I wanted to push my app to Heroku and coming up with the below error. Before that let me say that I have very little experience of coding and have never used Heroku or git before. I have tried alot of queries on Stackoverflow and other forums for a similar issue but no luck so far.

```
     error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o.d" failed with exit status 1
remote:              ----------------------------------------
remote:          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-50_9dq23/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-50_9dq23/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ya14jibf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-96iudfnx/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-96iudfnx/overlay/include/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
remote:          WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
remote:          You should consider upgrading via the '/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
remote:          ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-96iudfnx/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Cython 'numpy==1.9.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.12.1; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.1; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to frozen-temple-11992.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/frozen-temple-11992.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/frozen-temple-91169.git'
```

Comment: Git is not relevant here. The error is coming from heroku's build process. All of the `remote:` text is from Heroku itself. I don't know why your particular build failed, though it seems likely there should be some earlier message(s) as well, which might explain the reason.

Comment: Well, the complete log is quite long hence I trimmed some part of it. Let me show the complete log.